# Como pegar uma posição especifica do no foreach com PHP

Tags: php, rss

Estou criando uma aplicação que vou ter um RSS, e criei esse script em PHP:

```html
<?php
// permite requisições a urls externas
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);
 
// caminho do feed do meu blog
$feed = 'https://www.conjur.com.br/rss.xml';
// leitura do feed
$rss = simplexml_load_file($feed);
// limite de itens
$limit = 1;
// contador
$count = 0;
 
// imprime os itens do feed
if($rss)
{
    foreach ( $rss->channel->item as $item )
    {
        // formata e imprime uma string
        printf('<a href="%s" title="%s" >%s</a><br />', $item->link, $item->title, $item->title);
        // incrementamos a variável $count
        $count++;
        // caso nosso contador seja igual ao limite paramos a iteração
        if($count == $limit) break;
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Não foi possível acessar o blog.';
}
```

E preciso exibir um bloco com apenas uma noticia e depois mais 4, porém a primeira não pode repetir nas outras 4.

Qual seria a melhor forma pra fazer isso? Alguém pode me ajudar por favor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se existe em um array cada um desses RSS, se não ele vai adicionar esse link, assim fica mais fácil para ser manipulado posteriormente, podendo assim até exibir quantas e como quiser.

Fica assim um exemplo em base ao seu código:

```
<?php
// permite requisições a urls externas
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);

// caminho do feed do meu blog
$feed = 'https://www.conjur.com.br/rss.xml';
// leitura do feed
$rss = simplexml_load_file($feed);
// limite de itens
$limit = 1;
// contador
$count = 8;
$noticias = array();

// imprime os itens do feed
if($rss)
{
    foreach ( $rss->channel->item as $item )
    {
        // formata e imprime uma string
        //printf('<a href="%s" title="%s" >%s</a><br />', $item->link, $item->title, $item->title);
        $link = $item->link;
        $titulo = $item->title;

        $noticia = "<a href='$link' title='$titulo'>$titulo</a><br />";

        if(!in_array($noticia,$noticias)){
            array_push($noticias,$noticia);
        }
        // incrementamos a variável $count
        $count++;
        // caso nosso contador seja igual ao limite paramos a iteração
        if($count == $limit) break;
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Não foi possível acessar o blog.';
}

var_dump($noticias);
?>
```